# python break keeps closing the script after printing data

Tags: python

I have a piece of code I trying to get working, it's supposed to print a list of trade history. I only need it to print the last row. I was able to get that to work but, I also want it to loop every time.sleep(60)

The break is needed in order for the correct data to print. unfortunately, it closes the script after printing the data. any suggestions?

```
exchange.load_markets ()

symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
from_id = '0'
params = { 'fromId': from_id }
previous_from_id = from_id

all_trades = []

while True:

    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Fetching with params', params)
    trades = exchange.fetch_my_trades(symbol, None, None, params)
    print('Fetched', len(trades), 'trades')
    if len(trades):
        last_trade = trades[len(trades) - 1]
        if last_trade['id'] == previous_from_id:
            break
        else:
            params['fromId'] = last_trade['id']
            previous_from_id = last_trade['id']
            all_trades = all_trades + trades
    else:
        break

#print('Fetched', len(all_trades), 'trades')
for i in range(0, len(trades)):
    trade = trades[i]
    with open("recent.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(trade['price']))
        print (trade['date'], trade['price'], trade['amount'])
        f.close()
```

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) fix your indentation.  Un-indented  python cannot be understood.  (2) give more of the program.   This code must be inside a loop somewhere (otherwise "break" would be an error).  If we don't see the loop and also see your program logic, we can't possibly help.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, any example input, expected output, and actual output. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: I've edited the code. as far as the indentation goes, I've tried messing with it, but things get wonky.

Comment: `exchange` is not defined

Comment: The indentation looks good now. When Paul left that comment, there was no indentation at all, which made the code invalid

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Should the program start over again from the beginning after printing the output? If so, you're going to need an outer loop for that.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I was hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't test your code, or additions to it, because it is not [complete and self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Instead, here is a stripped-down demo program that mimics the same structure:

```
responses = []
print('Enter as many responses as you would like. Press enter on a blank line '
      'to see output.')

while True:
  response = input('Response: ')
  if response:
    responses.append(response)
  else:
    break

print('Output:')
for response in responses:
  print(f'***{response}***')
```

Like your actual program, this one creates an empty list, adds to it repeatedly in a while loop, and then, after breaking out of that loop, loops through the list in a for loop to print the output. Also like yours, the program exits as soon as it's done printing the output.

To make the whole thing repeat, put it all inside an outer while loop. Putting a call to `time.sleep` at the end of this outer loop will cause it to pause in between.

```
import time

while True:
  responses = []
  print('Enter as many responses as you would like. Press enter on a blank '
        'line to see output.')

  while True:
    response = input('Response: ')
    if response:
      responses.append(response)
    else:
      break

  print('Output:')
  for response in responses:
    print(f'***{response}***')

  time.sleep(3)
```

This will repeat indefinitely, until you halt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.